# SQL - conversion issue between nvarchar and money

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am trying to convert nvarchar(255) data type in to money and i am getting this error message: "Cannot convert a char value to money. The char value has incorrect syntax."

I found on Stockoverflow few things that suggest I add isNull in format bellow but i am still getting the same error.

```
SUM(isnull(cast(tbl_ALL_DATA_REPORT.[30_days_ago_sales] as money),0)) AS SumOf30_Days_Ago,
```

Any idea what I might doing wrong here?

[image]

Comment: I would stay away from the actual money type. Here is a chart of the valid data conversion types. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/data-type-conversion-database-engine

Comment: Can you also provide a few examples of the data you are trying to convert?

Comment: @ Jacob H - I took a snapshot of few rows. I hope you can see it. SO i have NULL valus and i have 10535.950000001 or 520.190000000005 etc.

Answer (score 0):

Some of the values has invalid characters to it.. You can try using try_cast

```
declare @n nvarchar(50) = '50n.25'
select isnull(try_cast(@n as money), 0)
```

In your scenario

```
SUM(isnull(try_cast(tbl_ALL_DATA_REPORT.[30_days_ago_sales] as money),0)) AS SumOf30_Days_Ago,
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this, with your ISNULL inside the CAST:

```
SUM(cast(ISNULL(tbl_ALL_DATA_REPORT.[30_days_ago_sales],0) as DECIMAL(19,12))) AS SumOf30_Days_Ago,
```

Also I changed your MONEY to DECIMAL as MONEY has a maximum of 5 decimal places.

Comment: @Jackob H - I tried this and i am getting :" Error converting data type nvarchar to numeric."

Comment: I would say try testing with a single value. It could be data related.

Answer (score 0):

You more than likely may have an invalid character or something not a number as part of the dataset that cannot convert.  Check that data is actually 'numeric' before making assumptions as such:

```
DECLARE @X TABLE (val VARCHAR(8));

INSERT INTO @X (val) VALUES (NULL), ('abc'),('4'),('%&Crazy')

Select 
  val AS ASIS
, ISNULL(val, 0) AS firstCastWillWorkForNullsNotMuchElse
, CASE WHEN ISNUMERIC(ISNULL(val, 0)) <> 0 THEN ISNULL(val, 0) ELSE 0 END AS secondCastToCheckNumeric
, CAST(CASE WHEN ISNUMERIC(ISNULL(val, 0)) <> 0 THEN ISNULL(val, 0) ELSE 0 END AS MONEY) AS thirdCastDoesItAll
From @X
```